# Unhandled exception. Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name: Index

Tags: c#

I am having the problem above when I try to shoot a paintball in my program. The class (Paintballs) code is below.

```
class Paintballs
{
    public List<Point> myClick;

    public Paintballs()
    {            
        myClick = new List<Point>();
    }

    public void add(Point location)
    {
        myClick.Add(location);                    
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        foreach (Point p in myClick)
        {
            g.FillEllipse(Brushes.Blue, p.X, p.Y, 20, 20);
        }            
    }

    public Point getPoints(int hit)
    {
        return myClick[hit];
    }     
}
```

When I debug the program, the error is on the line in the getPoints method "return myClick[hit]. Below is my form1.

```
namespace AmazingPaintball
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Random positionX = new Random();
        Random positionY = new Random();
        Target einstein;
        int count = 0;
        Paintballs pBalls = new Paintballs();
        Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();

        //Foreach loop
        //Draw paintballs first
        //then target

        SoundPlayer wavPlayer = new SoundPlayer();
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Point point = new Point(positionX.Next(0, 638), positionY.Next(0, 404));
            einstein = new Target(point);
            ptrEinstein.Location = point;
        }

        private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            pBalls.paint(e.Graphics);
        }

        private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            ptrEinstein.Location = einstein.Move(e.KeyData);
            pictureBox1.Update();
            pictureBox1.Refresh();       
        }

        private void pictureBox1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {            
            pBalls.add(e.Location);
            pictureBox1.Refresh();
            count++;

            Point shotHit = pBalls.getPoints(count);

            if (ptrEinstein.Location == shotHit)
            {
                stopwatch.Stop();
                MessageBox.Show("It took " + count + " shots and " + stopwatch.Elapsed + " seconds to hit the target");
            }            
        }       

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            stopwatch.Start();
        }          
    }
}
```

In form1, the problem appears to be in the `picturebox1_MouseClick` event. The `count` variable I wasn't sure if I should keep it at 0 or 1. Please let me know. Thank You

Comment: Try increment count after getting shotHit. It seems that you tries to get alway index one bigger than array size. Insted of that you can use Last() method for List in this particular example.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you're incrementing the count before you call pBalls.getPoints(count). Let's walk through what your program does when you first interact with it:

1. The picturebox1_MouseClick event is triggered.
2. The pBalls List of points adds an element and now has exactly one element (at index 0) with the point of the mouse location.
3. count is incremented from 0 to 1.
4. Your program runs pBalls.getPoints(count); but count is 1. The pBalls List of points only has one element, and it is in index 0. myClick[1] is being called but you are looking for myClick[0], the point you just added.

You can either increment count **after** calling pBalls.getPoints(count) or pass in the true index value with pBalls.getPoints(count-1);

Answer (score 0):

> count++;
>   Point shotHit = pBalls.getPoints(count);

this is wrong
you have to pass count -1 instead in  pBalls.getPoints(count-1);

or
increment after you get the shotHit

Answer (score 0):

The problem occurs in the following condition. lets assume we have a list.

// create a list of string type

```
List<string> lstString = new List<string>();
```

// add 3 values in the list

```
for(int i = 0 ; i<3 i++)
{
 lstString.Add("number" + i);
}
```

Now the length of the string is 3 .

when you write

```
lstString[0] it gives you number0
lstString[1] // //    //  number1
lstString[2] // //    //  number2
```

but if you write

```
lstString[3]
```

it throw exception because you pass the index which does not occur in the list. or in other words the index number is greater the the indexes in lstString.

This is exactly what you are doing here

```
private void pictureBox1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {            
            pBalls.add(e.Location); // you add element at index 0
            pictureBox1.Refresh();
            count++; // count++ mean count = 1;

            // now you passing 1 but the list only has zero index right. 
            Point shotHit = pBalls.getPoints(count); 

            if (ptrEinstein.Location == shotHit)
            {
                stopwatch.Stop();
                MessageBox.Show("It took " + count + " shots and " + stopwatch.Elapsed + " seconds to hit the target");
            }            
        }
```

**Solution :**

```
 private void pictureBox1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
            {            
                pBalls.add(e.Location); // you add element at index 0
                pictureBox1.Refresh();           

                Point shotHit = pBalls.getPoints(count); 

                if (ptrEinstein.Location == shotHit)
                {
                    stopwatch.Stop();
                    MessageBox.Show("It took " + count + " shots and " + stopwatch.Elapsed + " seconds to hit the target");
                 }   

               count++; // increment at the end of the method.        
            }
```